# remove rows of matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab

If I have a matrix `X` with only one column and it has some negative values in some rows. How can I remove only the negative values?

Example:

```
X=[-1; 2; 3; -4; 5]
```

should become:

```
X=[2; 3; 5]
```

Also, how can I remove values from

```
y=[1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
```

based on where the negative values in `X` are found? `y` should be `[2; 3; 5]` after this operation.

Comment: You can just use logical indexing: `Xnew = X(X>0);`

Comment: If I have x and y matrices. when I delete any negative row in x matrix, I want also delete the same row in matrix y. How can I do it?

Comment: example:
X=[-1; 2; 3; -4; 5]
y=[1; 2; 3; 4; 5]

after

X=[2; 3; 5]
y=[2; 3; 5]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing negative values from `X`:

You can either reassign `X` to a vector which only contains the values of `X` which are not negative:

```
>> X = X(X>=0)
X =
     2
     3
     5
```

or delete the negative values from `X`:

```
>> X(X<0) = []
X =
     2
     3
     5
```

Removing values from `y` based on the indices of negative values in `X` is similar. Either reassign:

```
>> y = y(X>=0)
y =
     2
     3
     5
```

Or delete:

```
>> y(X<0) = []      
y =
     2
     3
     5
```

If you want to modify both vectors based on the negative values in `X` remember to do the operation to `y` first or store a logical vector for the positions where `X<0`. For example:

```
>> ind = X < 0;
>> X(ind) = []
X =
     2
     3
     5
>> y(ind) = []
y =
     2
     3
     5
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Appreciate your beautiful helps